# How to add Kotlin Serialization to new Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, serialization

I'm having a heck of a time adding Kotlin serialization to a new Android project. I'm using `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2`.

When I add the plugin to the project-level `build.gradle` (see below), I get this sync error:

```
Build file '/Users/sean/Desktop/code/GradleTest/app/build.gradle' line: 3

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'.
   > Could not create an instance of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension.
      > Companion

* Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android']

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
```

Here's the project-level `build.gradle` where I've attempted to add the plugin:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.7.10'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's the app module `build.gradle` which is just the default one that's generated when you create a new project:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sthomas.gradletest"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
//    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2'
}
```

Here's `settings.gradle` which is also default:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "GradleTest"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 36):

First step is on `build.gradle` from *project level*: You forgot the `apply false` in front of the version in the plugin line.

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Second step is on `build.gradle` from *app module*: Apply the `plugin` and add the `dependency`.

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.3'
}
```

With that your project should work, but I would like to draw attention to a possible incompatibility issue if you use different versions of `Koltin` and `Kotlin Plugins`. And since you are using `Compose`, it is necessary to pay attention that the `Compiler` version of `Compose` needs to be compatible with the `Kotlin` version as well and that currently the `Compiler` version of `Compose` is no longer linked to versions of other `Compose` libraries. To know more you can take a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin).

So, to improve version compatibility in your project you can do this:

```gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_ver = '1.7.10'
        compose_compiler_ver = '1.3.0'
        compose_ver = '1.2.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_ver" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version "$kotlin_ver" apply false
}

// ...
```

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

android {
    // ...

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler_ver
    }

    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ver"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ver"

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.3'

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Kotlin DSL** then you can follow the below steps
add the below code in the level gradle file

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.7.10" apply false
```

Go to app level gradle file
add the below code in the plugin

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
..
..
..
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
}
```

add the below dependency in the dependency section

```
// KotlinX Serialization
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2")
```