# kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, serialization

Consider:

[image: LogCat error]

[image: Serialisable error]

> kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this annotation would not be processed. Make sure that you've setup your buildscript correctly and re-import project.

Till yesterday, the same code and the same dependencies were working fine, but now they are not. I don’t understand why. This is my dependency in: `build.gradle.kts (:app)` file.

`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2")`

My [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) dependencies code is:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.beautyapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.beautyapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    implementation ("com.github.ismaeldivita:chip-navigation-bar:1.4.0")

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1")



    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2")
    annotationProcessor ("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0")

    implementation ("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")

    implementation ("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2")

}
```

Comment: Kotlin serialization requires applying a _plugin_ in addition to declaring the appropriate _dependency_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73506975/6395627) (I suspect it's only necessary to apply the plugin in the app module). Note if you're using the Kotlin DSL then you can use the `kotlin("plugin.serialization")` shorthand for applying the plugin.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77763069/edit). Thanks in advance.